# AngularJS routing injection

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to delay loading of a controller until my AJAX request has returned for the particular item.  In each controller, I define the route and controller like:

```
define(['app'], function(app){

  app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/app-builder/:id', {
          templateUrl: 'views/app-builder.html',
          controller: 'AppBuilderCtrl',
          resolve: {
              resolvedVal: function($routeParams, AppsModel) {
                  return AppsModel.findOne($routeParams.id);
              }
          }
      });
  }]);

  app.controller('AppBuilderCtrl',  [function() { .... }]);

});
```

Problem is `$routeParams` does not have the property `id` when `resolvedVal` is called.  What am I missing here?  If this isn't the right approach, what is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider) of `resolve`:

> Be aware that ngRoute.$routeParams will still refer to the previous route within these resolve functions. Use $route.current.params to access the new route parameters, instead.

This should work:

```
  resolve: {
      resolvedVal: function($route, AppsModel) {
          return AppsModel.findOne($route.current.params.id);
      }
  }
```

Comment: What would be the optimal way to pass the XHR to the controller from that?

Comment: @amcdnl The best way is for your AppsModel.findOne to return a promise. If any of resolve dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved before the controller is instantiated. If the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected. I use restangular which always returns a promise, so AppsMopdel.findOne can be implemented like Restangular.one('company',id).get();

Comment: Ya, mine are returning a promise.  Oh, they are injected into the controller you mean?

Comment: Thats beautiful ... figured it out!  Thanks again!

Comment: @amcdnl Yes, so your controller definition would then have a 'resolvedVal', e.g. app.controller('AppBuilderCtrl', ['$scope', 'resolvedVal', function($scope, resolvedVal){}]);